# How to translate "it is what it is" ,etc.?

Tags: translation

How to translate:

- "It is what it is"
- "I am what I am"
- "They are what they are"

Suppose phrase means "it" etc. are difficult to characterize or classify.

Comment: Removed biblical reference as you already provided the translation

Comment: Above phrases may be in answer to the question, "what is it?", etc. following differing assertions about "it",  some saying "it is nonsense", some "it is wisdom"  etc.

Comment: The original meaning in English isn't clear from the question. "It is what it is" seems to mean idiomatically "fxck it, we will unwillingly deal with it". But OP says it's used as an answer to "what is it". Please clarify your question, at least put more context into it.

Comment: read preceding comment?

Answer (score 2):

- "It is what it is" (imply it can't be changed)

(事情)就是這樣

- "I am what I am" (imply I can't be changed)

我就是這樣

- "they are what they are"  (imply they can't be changed)

他們就是這樣

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to disagree with the distinguished colleague 唐后
We think "I am what I am." is better translated:

'我就是我。‘

Comment: 我就是我 means " I am who I am" (not other person) ; while " I am what I am" describe what kind of person I am, for example: "a pragmatic man" (and that can't be changed). My name is  not 唐后.

Comment: Old English hwa "who," sometimes "what; anyone, someone; each; whosoever," from Proto-Germanic *hwas. My Chinese friends disagree with your interpretation. Fundamentally, who means 'what person', note the 'hwa'. Nota bene: everything changes! Is who you are not what you are?

Comment: There is no need to apologise if you disagree with others. But you need to present more supporting arguments. Here I think the problem is because OP's question isn't clear in English anyway.

Answer (score 0):

These are overused terms commonly considered meaningless nowadays.

The meaning is broad and vague and depends on situations.  Sometimes it can mean "本該如此" and sometimes it may mean "幹!"  (i.e., "fxck it").